# Can a position variable have an infintesimal in it?

Tags: classical-mechanics, calculus, stability

I've been pondering unstable systems, such as a perfectly round rock atop a smooth hill.  At the top of the hill is a metastable point where the rock could roll either way after an arbitrary amount of time at the top.

What can we say about the highest point which is guaranteed to roll to the right, and not to the left.  If the position of the top is $x=x_0$, is there a position $x=x_0+dx$ which is guaranteed to fall in the positive direction?

My experience with infintesimals is limited to a few uses taught in calculus (such as on an integral), and this doesn't seem to be one of those cases.

Comment: You may be pondering the [Norton's dome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton%27s_dome).

Comment: I think in ordinary classical mechanics the answer to your question is negative because then the position vector is a real vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$. However, I guess that it should be possible to replace the field of real numbers with the field of [hyperreals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number) and in this variant of classical mechanics the answer to your question would be positive. I'm not sure whether anybody tried, whether it stumbles on some issues and whether it turns out productive in resolving questions of stability like Norton's dome. I'd be curious to find out, too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any positive d$x$ is guaranteed to fall in finite time. For instance, imagine a triangular shape. If you start at position d$x$, the acceleration becomes a constant: $a=mg$sin$\theta$, and the position along the slope will be $x=dx+at$.
Even if the shape is smooth, and $a(0)=0$, any d$x$ will start a motion such that a finite speed will be reached in finite time: $d^2x/dt^2=f(x)$ then $v(x)=\int_{dx}^xf(x)/v(x)dx$